# can't upload data to realtime firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im new to using realtime database and decided to build a projects that also contains user registration and login.
for that i used the the firebase autentication system, but because it uses only email and password, i wanted to keep more information in the real time database so taht i could acsses that using the uid given to each user.

the registeration process works fine and i can see the new users in firebase autentication, but
for some reason i dont understand, the extra information that i try to save is not being uploaded to the database no matter what i try.

this is the code i wrote

```
    public void tryRegister(View view){
    authService.createUserWithEmailAndPassword
            (this.email.getText().toString(),this.password.getText().toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    String uid = authService.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    Map<String, String> userDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    userDetails.put("username", this.username.getText().toString());
                    DatabaseReference usersInfo = database.getReference("usersInfo");
                    usersInfo.child(uid).setValue(userDetails);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    finish();
                }
                else{
                    this.failedReg.setText("error in the registration process");
                }
            });
}
```

app level dependencies:

```
dependencies {

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'}
```

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: If at the start of the `tryRegister` method call `database.getReference("test").setValue(true);` does that get written to the database? If not, the problem has nothing to do with the authentication and is purely about database access.

Comment: hi!
i think so to but wonderd if i have missed something.
anyway, i set the read and write rules to true, but i still cant upload the required information to the realtime database. 
can you give me directions on other things i should check? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I executed your code, data is getting added to Realtime Database without any issue.

[image: Realtime Database sample]

I guess you have not given `write` access in your firebase settings. Please check whether you have given `write` access in your rules section as shown below

[image: Realtime Database Rules]

For your reference, I have added the working code.

I have just included `addOnCompleteListener()` while adding data to the database. So that application will call `finish()` only when data is successfully added to the database.

This may also be the issue in your case. Because adding any value to the real-time database happens asynchronously. It may fail when the application is closed before adding the data to the database.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance ();
        Button signIn = findViewById ( R.id.button );
        signIn.setOnClickListener ( v -> tryRegister () );
    }

    public void tryRegister () {
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword ( "test@gmail.com", "password" )
                .addOnCompleteListener ( this, task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful ()) {
                        String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser ().getUid ();
                        Map<String, String> userDetails = new HashMap<> ();
                        userDetails.put ( "username", "test@gmail.com" );
                        DatabaseReference usersInfo = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ( "users" );
                        usersInfo.child ( uid ).setValue ( userDetails ).addOnCompleteListener ( task1 -> {
                            Log.d ( "INFORMATION", "Added" );
                            setResult ( RESULT_OK );
                            finish ();
                        } );
                    } else {
                        Log.d ( "INFORMATION", "Error" );
                    }
                } );
    }
}
```

Hope any of the above solutions helps you!

Comment: Thank tou for your answer!

i have set the rules so they will match what you wrote and added the oncomlete listner on the setvalue function too.
still, i have the same problem only now the registration activity dosent finish.

can you give me directions on where should i check for the problem?
maybe i havent set something in my project?

Comment: I hope you are using the above piece of code for new registrations alone. Because the above code will be executed and your activity will be finished only when a new sign up is occurring. If you are trying to sign up with the same credentials, then task.isSuccessful() will be false, so finish() will not be called.  Before retrying, delete the existing user created in authentication section of your firebase console and then try signing up

Comment: im deleting the users added after i run the code, but still, the task1.isSuccessful() (the one that we set for the setvalue function) always comesback false..
maybe there is something i needed to install differenly? 
i just dont understand why it won't work